# java.io.File.toURI() IO bound?

Tags: java

I'm profiling J2EE application responsible for storing binary files on disk.  During profiling, we've discovered a great deal of IO bottlenecks, which we have a plane to address.  However, we've also seen slowdown on this line of code:

```
// Example URI path
String filename = "/path/to/file.txt"  

// This line at load takes almost 500 ms
return new File(filename).toURI();
```

The method in question takes in a file path and returns a file path where the file can be written.

Since the slowdown only occurs at load, I am guessing the process is IO bound during this line.  Is this the case?  If so, is there a better way to assign a URI that will perform better?

Comment: what platform are you running on and which version of java? This should be trivial! If this really takes 1/2 second, you should sue Oracle and/or get off the platform

Comment: what fileName contains path to file on local machine or remote machine or external device. Do you have required permissions.

Comment: @ControlAltDel We're pursuing both software and hardware fixes.  The 1/2 second is intermittent, and seems to correlate strongly with large spikes in file read time, leading to the conclusion I drew in the description.  Our platform is CentOS with Java 6.

Comment: @sudmong Permissions don't seem to be a factor.  The file share is remote, however.

Comment: that could be cause for delay.. you may note the time it takes for local file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the source code for that method:

```
   public URI toURI() {
    try {
        File f = getAbsoluteFile();
        String sp = slashify(f.getPath(), f.isDirectory());
        if (sp.startsWith("//"))
        sp = "//" + sp;
        return new URI("file", null, sp, null);
    } catch (URISyntaxException x) {
        throw new Error(x);     // Can't happen
    }
    }
```

The "getAbsoluteFile()" is indeed IO bound, as it has to access the filesystem to resolve any relative paths into absolute paths (via FileSystem.resolve() method down the chain).

Comment: Thanks!  We may explore the effects of skipping the toURI() method, instead using a predetermined URI prefix.